# Encrypt files using Android shell tools

Tags: twrp, encryption, shell

I want to encrypt and decrypt some files (symmetrically and asymmetrically) on the Android command line, including the one in the TWRP recovery. Is there a program which can do this?

I've tried googling but I've found nothing so far. The only thing which comes close is [this](https://github.com/guardianproject/gnupg-for-android) GPG port from the GuardianProject, but it seems rather old and is unmaintained.

Comment: You can install Termux from Fdroid to get a well maintained command-line environment including gog openssl and so on. If you have a recovery that allows to mount and decrypt user data files and run executables from that partition this might als work from within recovery.

Comment: You want ARM64 static binary of [AESCrypt](https://www.aescrypt.com/)? But AES is only symmetric.

Comment: Yeah something like this would be great, thanks for the pointer. I am thinking of compiling openssl for ARM64 since it offers a _HUGE_ range of crypto operations.

Comment: [aescrypt_static_aarch64_v3.16](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=15664248565197198337)